# How do I get different navigation controllers based on what disclosure indicator in swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

I'm very new to swift. I added disclosure indicators to my TableView. I want to make the different disclosure indicators lead to different view controllers. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your ViewController with multiple ViewControllers in your storyboard giving each storyboard segue an identifier. Then call self.performSegueWithIdentifier when you have identified which cell the user has selected. For example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", sender: self)
    }
    ...
}
```